# Trigger INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged for property on dependent / nested view model

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a nested view model structure like in the following example:

```
public class SubViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            // calculate result and return it
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SubViewModel Sub { get; set; }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // executes code that changes some parameters such that Sub.Property changes

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Sub.Property"));
    }
}
```

There are situations when a change happens in the parent view model that influences the properties on the nested view model. In other words, a property (`SubViewModel.Property` in the example) on the child view model changes, but the child view model does not know that.

I want to invoke `PropertyChanged` in a way that tells the WPF binding engine that the property `Property` on the child view model `Sub` has changed. I tried all the following options, but none has worked so far:

```
OnPropertyChanged("");
OnPropertyChanged("*");
OnPropertyChanged("Sub");
OnPropertyChanged("Sub.Property");
OnPropertyChanged("Sub.*");
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Please note: I know that the parent view model could call a method on the child view model which raises a `PropertyChanged` event on the child view model. I have my reasons to not do it that way.

Comment: Maybe you should explain your reasons for doing it this way. Then we might be able to help you figure out a better way to achieve your goals.

Comment: Seriously I still don't quite understand what you meant, but you can make `OnPropertyChanged` `internal`, then call `Sub.OnPropertyChanged("Property")`. I am kind of pure guessing what you want, but who knows - this may be the thing you need.

Comment: Why can’t you simply raise the PropertyChanged event from each property in sub view model. So that when you change the subviewmodelinstance.PropertyName in main view model, the corresponding event will be raised automatically. It’s the normal way. I don’t think you need to raise the event by calling a function in the sub view model.

Comment: What's happening inside the getter of `SubProperty`? Does it read a property of `ViewModel`? Please explain what exactly the dependency is.

Answer (score 0):

- Call OnPropertyChanged when you change the SubViewModel.
- your SubviewModel should be Created in your MainViewModel
- In your View you must call: "DataContext ={Binding Sub}"
- In your SubView there MUSTNOT Be a word of "DataContext"
- In your SubView you have to bind the properties like this:
  "Example = {Binding MyProperty}"

  ```
  public class SubViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     private string _MyProperty;
     public string MyProperty
     {
         get { return _MyProperty; }
         set { _MyProperty = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }

     #region NotifyPropertyChanged
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string info = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
     }
     #endregion
  }

  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     private SubViewModel _Sub;
     public SubViewModel Sub
     {
         get { return _Sub; }
         set { _Sub = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }

     public void MyMethod()
     {
      // executes code that changes some parameters such that Sub.Property changes

         NotifyPropertyChanged();
     }

     #region NotifyPropertyChanged
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string info = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
     }

     #endregion
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a cyclic dependency between `ViewModel` and `SubViewModel`. This leads to strong coupling between both which is never good. I propose a different solution. `INotifyPropertyChanged` already provides the infrastructure to do exactly what you want.

So `SubViewModel` has a dependency on `ViewModel`. I presume it needs the value of one of `ViewModel`'s properties to calculate the value of `SubViewModel.Property`. So the solution is quite naturally to hook up `SubViewModel` to `ViewModel.PropertyChanged`:

```
public class SubViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ViewModel parent;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SubViewModel(ViewModel parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        // Hook up to parent's property changes.
        this.parent.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SubProperty"));
    }

    public string SubProperty
    {
        get { return parent.Property; }
    }
}
```

Notice how the dependency is made explicit by expecting a `ViewModel` in the construcor of `SubViewModel`. This way the next programmer sees immediately that a `SubViewModel` needs a `ViewModel` in order to work correctly and cannot construct a non-functioning `SubViewModel`.

The event handler defined in the constructor is of course quite simplified. Better make it a private method that checks `e.PropertyName` before it does anything. Anyway, it's basic purpose is to notify all clients that subscribed to `SubViewModel`'s property changes as soons as `ViewModel.Property` has been changed.

You better not have a relation from `ViewModel` to `SubViewModel` in order to avoid a cyclic dependency. Get rid of the `Sub` property and implement `ViewModel` like so:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string property;
    public string Property
    {
        get { return this.property; }
        set
        {
            this.property = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Property"));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the implementation of `ViewModel` looks exactly like any other `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. The parent does not need to know what its children do with its values. Only the client's of `ViewModel` implement the logic to handle `ViewModel`'s property changes, *not* the parent.

Here is a working example for testing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vQJBak

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in `SubViewModel`, and raise that event whenever something changes. Parent viewmodel will subscribe to that event.

Thats what events are for.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around (i.e. `SubViewModel` subscribes to `ViewModel.PropertyChanged`)?

Comment: @Abbondanza You get the idea .